# cakephp & httpd.conf issues on windows based apache server (wamp)

Tags: mod-rewrite, cakephp, wamp, apache

**So, i was wondering if some one could clarify following occurrence and maybe suggest how I could tackle this.**

*sorry for the weird coloring of the code*

Let me explain the set up first. I have wamp server installed and it is located physically on one hd and then my development files are located on separate hd. So i have added alias to access specific dev folder

**in httpd.conf** i have following

```
ServerRoot D:/Program Files/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.11  
Listen 80  
ServerName localhost:80  
DocumentRoot D:/Program Files/wamp/www  
<Directory />  
    Options FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride None  
    Order deny,allow  
    Deny from all  
</Directory>  
<Directory D:/Program Files/wamp/www/>  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride all  
    Order Allow,Deny  
    Allow from all  
</Directory>
```

**following is in seperate conf file and included into httpd.conf**

```
Alias /project_birthday_planner "E:/Development/--- Projects-Full/PROJECT - BirthdayPlanner/trunk/"  
<Directory E:/Development/--- Projects-Full/PROJECT - BirthdayPlanner/trunk/>  
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews  
    AllowOverride All  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all  
</Directory>
```

in my **E:/Development/--- Projects-Full/PROJECT - BirthdayPlanner/trunk/** i have my cakephp directories and files

**here is the problem**

my mode rewrite is turned on and my htaccess files for following cakephp folders are as following,

**root of the cakephp**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on  
    RewriteBase /  
    RewriteRule ^$ /app/webroot/ [L]  
    RewriteRule (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>
```

***\app***

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on  
    RewriteBase /  
    RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/ [L]  
    RewriteRule (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>
```

***\app\webroot***

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteBase /  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]  
</IfModule>
```

when I access **/project_birthday_planner** i get following error **404 Not Found**

```
**Not Found**  
The requested URL /app/webroot/ was not found on this server.
```

if i set DocumentRoot to my cakephp folder or move cakephp folders and files to initial DocucumentRoot folder, all fires up and works.

**question is**
how do i tackle this issue, is this something that inherently comes with the use of apache Alias
or am I missing some piece

should this set up be tackled via VirtualHost then?

thank you so much in advance

Comment: is this a windows based issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to point the Rewritebase to the right path ... see [here](http://cookingwithcakephp.blogspot.com/2008/04/installing-cakephp-into-subdirectory.html)