# How to config .htaccess files of CakePHP in WampServer?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, wamp, wampserver

I'm absolutely confused about what I must do to run my sample in CakePHP...

I'm using WAMP Server and it is located in "C:/program files/wamp/" and I use another partition for my projects: "E:/Projects/".

there is a folder for Learning CakePHP: "**E:/Projects/cakephp/**". I've put all the CakePHP extracted contents in that folder (*consist of: index.php, .htaccess, readme.txt and folders: app, cake, plugins, vendors*)...

First, I set an alias name (**test**) in Apache that pointed to "**E:/Projects/cakephp/**", and it didn't work (*message:  Oops! This link appears to be broken.*)

After some search, I found that I must set the alias to another folder: "**E:/Projects/cakephp/app/webroot/**", and it worked perfectly and showed me the first page of CakePHP Framework.

I solved all the issues in the first page (*using the CakePHP manual*). I tried to follow CakePHP blog tutorial ... I made a model, a controler and a view page (all related to "posts" subject), but when I try to see the result I just received the first page of WAMP server (showing that there is some problem in the address)

I used the address: "**http://localhost/test/posts/index**" (that didn't work)
then, I tried to put index.php in the url: "**http://localhost/test/index.php/posts/index**" and it worked!

.htaccess files when I try to reach the root "**http://localhost/test/**" work perfect, I don't know what's wrong!

**xx** I found the same question in StackOverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330416/cakephp-httpd-conf-issues-on-windows-based-apache-server-wamp) . All of its settings is similar to mine except it seems he set the alias to the root of CakePHP, and it didn't work for me!

and actually I couldn't find how I can use the solution ([link](http://cookingwithcakephp.blogspot.com/2008/04/installing-cakephp-into-subdirectory.html)) that helped him, because I think it is a little different in my case!

My htaccess files for following cakephp folders are as following,

**root of the cakephp**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /test/
    RewriteRule ^$ /app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /test/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

**/app/webroot**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /test/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope someone can help me, I'm really exhausted...

thanks in advance for your time and your solutions!

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Yoohoooo! I found the answer! I had made many changes in all of my htaccess files! If you have this problem too, first remove all of your changes and then use this [link](http://www.chriscassell.net/log/2006/07/27/how_to_install_.htmlo) as a great help!
Hope it help you too! CHEEEEERS! MANY CHEEEEERS!! :D**

Answer (score 14):

1. Right click on the WAMP icon on your
   task bar
2. Then Hover over Apache Modules
3. Scroll down and make sure rewrite_module is ticked

Answer (score 2):

I actually got the same issue as you, but I don't remember how I solved it.

What I can assure you it's not a .htaccess issue, but a configuration error of Apache.

I *think* the part I modified was this one.

```
<Directory />
    #Options +Indexes
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    #Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Note how I commented some lines. Altough I can't confirm this, since I don't have the default configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, I did it in my httpd.conf, but nothing changed in result! I think this is a htaccess problem! I used many advices and many solutions that I found in another websites but I can't fix the problem!

Comment: I'm convinced it is not. Try installing WordPress and check if the URL structure is like `/wp/2010/12/post_title` or more like `/index.php/wp/2010/12...`

Comment: Actually, I have a wordpress in my localhost and I don't have problem with my wordpress... it works great

Comment: Ok, I just saw you modified the default .htaccess files. Try downloading CakePHP once again and extracting everything to a new folder, then access that folder via your localhost. Tell me how it works.

Comment: your advice helped me to find my mistake! Thank you very very much. ;) I found a very good blog that helped me and I placed it in the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and here is solution that worked for me

this is my `cakephp.conf` in wamp server

```
Alias /cakephp "d:/wamp/apps/cakephp/app/webroot" 

<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/cakephp/app/webroot">
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   Require local
</Directory>
```

This is `.htaccess` file in /cakephp (not changed anything)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ /webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

This is `.htaccess` file in /cakephp/app (not changed anything)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    /webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) /webroot/$1    [L]

</IfModule>
```

This is `.htaccess` file in /cakephp/app/webroot (changed)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cakephp
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webroot/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I just added line this line

```
RewriteBase /cakephp
```

After this I was able to launch url localhost/cakephp/index.php/posts/index

Hope this will help you to get started with CakePhp using WAMP Server

Answer (score 1):

use

```
  RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)  index.php/posts/index
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I placed it in my htaccess file but it show an error message in the result page (controller error)... I looked at many various solutions but they don't change this line "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]" but most of them try to change RewriteBase ... I tried many things, but without any good result.