# How to use .htaccess in WAMP Server?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

I searched in web for 2 days and I try to use htaccess in my local wamp but I can't! I know there is something wrong but I don't know where...

**First:** I activated "*rewrite_module*" in the apache menu, then I checked the phpinfo page and I saw that module added to its "*Loaded Modules*" part.

**Second:** I checked the httpd.conf and made some changes, it is the result (just important parts):

```
ServerRoot "c:/program Files/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.11"
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
DocumentRoot "c:/program Files/wamp/www/"

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
# AllowOverride None
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
AllowOverride all
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/program Files/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

**Next:** I made an alias to my workspace. Here is contents of its .conf file:

```
Alias /basic_test/ "e:/Projects/basic_test/"

<Directory "e:/Projects/basic_test/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Next:** I place a simple "index.php" and "test.php" in my workspace root and tested the alias by this addresses:
--> "*localhost/basic_test/index.php*"
--> "*localhost/basic_test/test.php*"
They worked perfectly...

**Finally**, I added a ".htaccess" file to the root of my workspace (beside index.php), and I wrote in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ test.php
</IfModule>
```

But the **problem** occurred when I tried to test the "`.htaccess`" by this address:
--> "*localhost/basic_test/index.php*"

It shows an error page with this message:

> Oops! This link appears to be broken.

Comment: Always look in your (Apache) error logs. You can use the Wamp icon for that (Apache -> Logs ?)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I look but I can't understand its problem, anyway it is a good advice, thank you. ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /basic_test/

RewriteRule ^index.php$ test.php
```

Comment: I have a question: if I try to edit alias ton point to another folder "e:/Projects/basic_test/new/path/" I must change that path in front RewriteBase?! ... could you please check my another question?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383451/how-to-config-htaccess-files-of-cakephp-in-wampserver

Answer (score 46):

Click on Wamp icon and open Apache/httpd.conf and search "#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so". Remove # as below and save it

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and restart all service.

Comment: can't start on wamp 2.4

Answer (score 24):

click: `WAMP icon->Apache->Apache modules->chose rewrite_module`

and do restart for all services.

Answer (score 4):

Open the httpd.conf file and search for

> "rewrite"

, then remove

> "#"

at the starting of the line,so the line looks like.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

then restart the wamp.

Answer (score 1):

if it related to hosting site then ask to your hosting to enable url writing   or if you want to enable it in local machine then check this youtube step by step tutorial related to enabling rewrite module in wamp apache 
https://youtu.be/xIspOX9FuVU?t=1m43s 
Wamp server icon -> Apache -> Apache Modules and check the rewrite module option
it should be checked 
Note its very important that after enable rewrite module  you should require to restart all services of wamp server