# How do I make htaccess work in WAMP?

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use .htaccess in WAMP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391530/how-to-use-htaccess-in-wamp-server)

I'm using Wamp Server 2.0 on Windows 7 (32-bit) and want to make use of .htaccess files. I'm kinda new to server configs in general but from what I understand I have to "activate" usage of htaccess files in the httpd.conf file of Apache?

I have done the following:

In my httpd.conf file I've added these lines:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Then I created a .htaccess file in my sites root directory with the following lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) /articles/index.php?slug=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [PT, L]
```

However, I keep getting 500 Internal Server Errors when I try to load up the page. If I comment out the RewriteRule it works though. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There's nothing in the apache error log concerning this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space in between the flags of your `RewriteRule`.  Also, you will need a `RewriteCond` to avoid infinite redirects.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php$
 RewriteRule ^articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) /articles/index.php?slug=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It's funny how a simple little space could cause that much of a problem :)

Comment: +1 Good answer. For other readers still having problems, other places to look are vhosts.conf (you may or may not have this file in your *AMP stack) and check settings in there, particularly to ensure that `AllowOverride All` is set as for me this ensured Apache 'saw' my .htaccess file and stopped ignoring it.