# .htaccess rewrite rule not working even after all the necessary changes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

working for rewrite rules for my website couples of days now but failed to do it successfully.
googled a lot and also found some very important threads here in stackoverflow,specially **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391530/how-to-use-htaccess-in-wamp-server)**. I have made all the changes which are mentioned in the web.Before i talk about the changes i made to my `httpd.conf`, i want share the directory structure of my `wamp`

root directory for my website is **`C:/wamp/www/dist`**. `index.php` and `.htaccess` files for my website are kept Within this ***dist*** folder and there are other sub-directories for other files for my website.

**MY CHANGES ::**

`wamp --> Apache --> Apache modules --> rewrite_module` checked it

```
       ----------------IN MY APACHE httpd.conf file----------------

 LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so //removed # sign from it

 <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/dist/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride all
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

and now i have created a `.htaccess` file in my **`C:/wamp/www/dist`** (index.php is also here)

so my `.htaccess` looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /dist/
     RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /dist/?path=$1
</IfModule>
```

**Result/Error ::** It is not working url remains the same(ugly) as before.no changes in url.

**Error Explained ::** from my any pages which are in other sub-directories i send  a request to my index.php which looks like `http://localhost/dist/?path=home` and after checking the value of path variable `index.php` includes necessary file.so I want to my url as `http://localhost/dist/home`.but as i said it is not working.my url still remains
`http://localhost/dist/?path=home` after creating **`.htaccess`** file

**Note 1 ::**  i checked **`phpinfo()`** the modules are loaded.

**Note 2 ::** I tried by removing `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` from `.htaccess` but it has no effect all are same again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `/dist/.htaccess` like this:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dist/

# Use %{THE_REQUEST} to make an external redirect from /dist/?path=home to /dist/home
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?path=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

## internal rewrite from /dist/home to /dist/?path=home
# not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`
- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: can you please explain your codes sir.. i dont know/understand the codes..i am copying it and if it runs please let me know how did it work because i am new to `.htaccess`

Comment: sir voted it up...can accept it after few minutes...can you please explain the error and changes

Comment: I have added explanation. You can also refer http://askapache.com/ as a good reference on this.

Comment: sir i have three queries... **1>** Should i write Line No. 4 & 5 only once for all my rules? ... **2>** should i repeat Line no. 6 & 7 for all my rules ... **3>** will it work for multiple url variables like if i want to rewrite `http://localhost/dist/?path=view_post&post_id=72&post_title=here goes_the_post_title`

Comment: Multiple parameters will need a new set of these 2 rules: 1. External redirect rule and 2. Internal rewrite rule. You will need to be careful using correct regex for that. Feel free to post a new question for more complex requirements since these rules cannot be posted in comments section.

Comment: sir i faced a problem with your solution .... thye problem is it is working for the first time only..for example if i pass `http://localhost/dist/?path=home` for the first time then it is working fine now my url is `http://localhost/dist/home/` but if i send now `http://localhost/dist/?path=jobs_post` it is failing now it is showing `http://localhost/dist/home?path=jobs_post` instead of `http://localhost/dist/jobs_post/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58270/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ritabrata-gautam).