# getting 404 not found error when refreshing web app deployed using ember cli

Tags: ember-cli

I was able to successfully deploy my web app in apache server(wamp) locally. So initially my URL looks like http://somehost.com/dshrestha/ and I can navigate to various routes for eg. http://somehost.com/dshrestha/home, http://somehost.com/dshrestha/contact etc via navigation links but then when I refresh the page on any of the routes, I get 404 Not Found error.

How can I overcome this issue? i even tried to redirect all requests to index.html by creating htaccess file but no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I found the solution in the next answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630973/4425050

Change the locationType from auto --> to hash

Answer (score 1):

Ok turned out it was an .htaccess thing I had to fix. Added these in my .htaccess to get things working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(?=jpg|png|gif|js|css|pdf|docx|htm)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html
```

Comment: did you try solution mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391530/how-to-use-htaccess-in-wamp-server

Answer (score 0):

its an old post, however, to make sure you can use bootstrap glyphicon and any other file that pg|png|gif|js|css|pdf|docx|htm, replace

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(?=jpg|png|gif|js|css|pdf|docx|htm)
```

with this

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```