# Error 404 when directly access to a route in EmberJS distribution app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have developed a web application with EmberJS and I want to deploy in a real server.

When I test in localhost with environment development and command `ember s`everything is OK, but when I create the distribution package with `ember build --environment=production` and deploy it using a webserver (in my case `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 4200` and also with a Apache server) I get the following error when I try to access directly to a route.

```
Error response

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
```

If I enter in `myaddress:4200` and navigate through links, nothing is wrong but if I want to refresh the web or change the url, the error 404 happened.

Comment: I m unsure how it is done with python but you will need to redirect all requests to your index.html file and only allow requests through if the file exists.

Comment: @Kitler how can I do that? What do you use to create your deploy server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python SimpleHTTPServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401815/python-simplehttpserver)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the question you say because I have tried to deploy it in a Apache server and the error is the same. Route does not exist

Comment: You asked about python's `SimpleHTTPServer`, the question is a duplicate of that question, and if you want apache then the question is a dupe of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845048/client-side-javascript-app-url-routing-with-no-hash-tag)

Comment: The answer to your problem is you need to configure your server be it apache/nginx or a potato to redirect all requests to index.html except for valid files such as images, css, js, etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ember/Ember-Cli Serving through Apache throws 404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535283/ember-ember-cli-serving-through-apache-throws-404)

Answer (score 0):

After check the question [Python SimpleHTTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401815/python-simplehttpserver) and one issue in ember repository, the solution that I have implemented is perform deploy through Apache server and creating a `.htaccess` file that redirect the traffic to index.html

```
Options FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Note that this will not work with python SimpleHTTPServer and requires apache.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include that I serve it through Apache. Thanks @Kitler!