# Block wamp homepage access from outside without creating Virtual Host

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have locally installed WAMP web server where different sites are hosted like

```
http://localhost/Web1/
http://localhost/Web2/
http://localhost/Web3/
```

Now the problem is that anyone can access my wamp homepage and all those hosted sites and even try to login in PHPMyAdmin. I want to restrict wamp homepage access that no one allows to access the wamp homepage from outside(Other than my PC).

Comment: from outside of what?

Comment: Outside of hosted location. Other than my PC.

Comment: Are you using WAMPServer specifically?

Comment: I am using WampServer 2.2

Comment: how about trying .htacces config file? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391530/how-to-use-htaccess-in-wamp-server) if you put `order deny,allow
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all` this will only allow your local pc access to that website.

Comment: The Dup links should explain, but basically you need to create a virtual host for localhost and all your other sites. Then the other sites can be `Require all granted` and localhost can use `Require local` As you are using a VERY OLD Version of WAMPServer though you will have to do the Virtual Host creation manually, the helper is only available in WAMPServer 3

Comment: @saur where should i place this file? additionally i don't want to restrict web access from outside i just want to restrict homepage of wamp.

Comment: @saur i have put 'order deny,allow allow from 127.0.0.1 deny from all' in httpd.conf but now website is not available from outside.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan .htaccess file block access to folder and its sub folder. example: if i put .htaccess  in my htdocs then no one will be able to access any of my website. hence if you want to block access to web1, web2 and web3..... then create the htaccess file and put them in each of the folder.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan no need to mess with http.conf, .htacces is a seperate file which you can create.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Gfk-Jt35gk) this will help you. my suggestion is you dont mess with httpd.conf file