# Change document root using .htaccess on wamp

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have scratching my head over it for a long time now. Can't manage to get it to work. (I am a noob with apache that can be one reason also). Ok here is the problem in nutshell. I am using wamp and I have a directory `Retailer`. There is another directory inside it which is called public that contains the index and otherfiles. I want to make this `public` directory document root. I want to achieve this with `.htaccess`

My Rewrite module for apache is turned on.

Here is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ test.php
```

And also I have tried

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/Retailer$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/Retailer$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

And I have tried

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://localhost/Retailer/$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://localhost/Retailer/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

But result in all these cases is the same. That is:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated
Ahmar

Comment: you want to create virtual host on wamp?

Comment: no I want to change document root using .htaccess

Comment: What are the URLs that you want to use after this change?

Comment: what do you mean? When I access localhost/Retailer it should access the public directory as root

Comment: you will get your all answer in that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383451/how-to-config-htaccess-files-of-cakephp-in-wampserver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this rule in your **`Retailer/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Retailer/

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Oh no, it suck a dirty hack!

Answer (score 3):

You should config this not in `.htaccess` file but in apache config file `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/project/Retailer/public"  
  ServerName "retailer.local"
  ServerAlias "www.retailer.local" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you need to update your `hosts` file with the next line:

```
127.0.0.1 retailer.local
```

And restart your web server!

Comment: And restart your web server too!